# Airflow DAG getting psycopg2.OperationalError when running tasks with KubernetesPodOperator

Tags: airflow, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks

**Context**

We are running `Airflow 2.1.4.` on a `AKS` cluster. The Airflow metadata database is an `Azure managed postgreSQL`(8 cpu). We have a DAG that has like 30 tasks, each task use a `KubernetesPodOperator` (using the apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes==2.2.0) to execute some container logic. Airflow is configured with the Airflow official HELM chart. The executor is `Celery`.

**Issue**

Usually the first like 5 tasks execute successfully (taking like 1 or 2 minute each) and get marked as done (and colored green) in the Airflow UI. The tasks after that are also successfully executed on AKS, but Airflow not marked as completed in Airflow as such. In the end this leads up to this error message and marking the already finished task as a fail:

```
[2021-12-15 11:17:34,138] {pod_launcher.py:333} INFO - Event: task.093329323 had an event of type Succeeded
...
[2021-12-15 11:19:53,866]{base_job.py:230} ERROR - LocalTaskJob heartbeat got an exception
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
Is the server running on host "psql-airflow-dev-01.postgres.database.azure.com" (13.49.105.208) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

**Similar posting**

This issue is also described in this post: https://www.titanwolf.org/Network/q/98b355ff-d518-4de3-bae9-0d1a0a32671e/y Where in the post a link to Stackoverflow does not work anymore.

The metadata database (Azure managed postgreSQL) is not overloading. Also the AKS node pool we are using does not show any sign of stress. It seems like the scheduler cannot pick up / detect a finished task after like a couple of tasks have run.

We also looked at several configuration option as stated [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.1.4/configurations-ref.html#kubernetes)

We are looking now for a number of days now to get this solved but unfortunately no success.

Anyone any idea's what the cause could be? Any help is appreciated!